# Interrupt AVSpeechUtterance and Resume Using WillSpeakRange Delegate in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avspeechsynthesizer

Using AVSpeechSynthesizer, if an utterance is going to be very long, I'd like to prompt user whether to cut it off or hear to end.

I'm tracking the length in the willSpeakRange delegate.

At a certain point, I would like to pause or stop the speech. And then ask the user whether to continue.

If I use the Pause functionality of the synthesizer on the original utterance, it does not seem to allow me to interrupt with "Do you want to hear to the end".

On the other hand, if I use the Stop functionality, it allows me to ask "Do you want to hear to the end" but we lose the place in the original utterance.

How can I pause or stop the original utterance and then either resume or capture the remaining text to start a new utterance that effectively completes the original one.

This is the code I am using:

```
let count = 0
func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString characterRange: NSRange, utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
count = count+1
if (count==limit) {
count = 0
//Pause option does not seem to allow interjection
self.voice.pauseSpeaking(at: AVSpeechBoundary.immediate)
//stop option loses place
self.voice.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)
//NEED TO CAPTURE UNSPOKEN TEXT IF I USE STOP OPTION
let speechString = utterance.speechString
let newRange = Range(characterRange, in: speechString)
//Store the remaining text to a variable       
remainingText = ???
self.speakSomething(text:",,Should I stop or continue?")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I use the Pause functionality of the synthesizer on the original utterance, it does not seem to allow me to interrupt with "Do you want to hear to the end".

The `pauseSpeaking` method  doesn't impact the queue to be spoken by the speech synthesis. It just pauses as long as you wish and allows to resume from where you left off but **you can't insert any new utterance on the fly** at this point following this pattern.

> On the other hand, if I use the Stop functionality, it allows me to ask "Do you want to hear to the end" but we lose the place in the original utterance.

The `stopSpeaking` method **removes any utterances yet to be spoken from the synthesizer’s queue**, that's why you can insert your new utterance but lose everything that was previously scheduled.

> How can I pause or stop the original utterance and then either resume or capture the remaining text to start a new utterance that effectively completes the original one.

According to what I explained above, **you have no choice but stopping the original utterance** for asking your question. I suggest this pattern:

1. Get the current spoken utterance thanks to the `AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` protocol.
2. Fire the `stopSpeaking` synthesizer method that will remove from the queue the utterances that haven't been spoken yet.
3. Create the utterance to ask the choice question and make the synthesizer read it out.
4. If the choice is to resume, create a new utterance from the location found at 1. until the end of your text and then resume.

If you don't know how to capture the unspoken text, take a look at this [example](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#speech-synthesis) *(ObjC, Swift)* that shows up the spoken word in bold text.

Add the following code snippet in the delegate method of this example to catch your remaining text for instance:

```
func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer,
                       willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString characterRange: NSRange,
                       utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {

    let remainingText = utterance.speechString.dropFirst(characterRange.location)
    //...
}
```

Following these steps, you could **Interrupt AVSpeechUtterance and Resume Using WillSpeakRange Delegate in Swift** as mentioned in your post title.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to capture the specific word being spoken--from your linked to example and also from this snippet at NSHipster https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-highlight-text-to-speech-words-being-read-using-avspeechsynthesizer but how do you get all the remaining text. I think characterRange from the delegate gives you the starting word but how do you get all the text to the end???

Comment: Look deeply at the example provided by the link: the length of your text is given by the 'utterance.speechString' in the delegate method ⟹ just write 'attributedString.lentgh' to get it. You have the starting point and the total amount of characters which is ideal to get a substring.

Comment: Strings and ranges are pretty complicated in Swift.  This is what I'm struggling with.

Comment: Wow your code was a heck of a lot easier than trying to get the end of the range and getting tied up in integer vs. UT8, open vs. closed ranges etc..  However, your snippet while close to perfect is not grabbing the beginning of a word. It's starting in middle of word   "k away, we're bound away" instead of "look away, we're bound away". which might be due to dropfirst. How would I start at beginning of  word "look" which I think is characterRange.lowerBound?

Comment: As I suggested, copy-paste the example provided by the link in a blank project and you'll see that the substring doesn't start in the middle of a word.

Comment: what is characterRange.location?

Comment: 'characterRange': https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesizerdelegate/1619681-speechsynthesizer and 'location': https://nshipster.com/nsrange/